# New reputation not calculated for only the black flair

Tags: bug, reputation, flair, combined-flair

Why is the black flair different than the other flair themes? The screenshots below are my flairs taken on the same time. With the same reputation and badges.

However you can see on the black flair that the reputation for Super User is missing but not on the normal, hotdog and clean flair.

[image: normal flair: 2.5k reputation for SO, Database administrators, game dev and SU][image: black flair: 2.3k reputation for SO, Database administrators and game dev][image: hotdog flair: 2.5k reputation for SO, Database administrators, game dev and SU][image: clean flair: 2.5k reputation for SO, Database administrators, game dev and SU]

Here you can check my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5766114/lu%C3%AFs).

---

**Update:**

A comment from @ShadowWizard shows me this. This is how he see my flair.

[image]

Comment: [Showing 2.5k for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QyifV.png) - try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: not for me. I see 2.3k on black, 2.5k on other three.

Comment: Flair is an image, so the black flair could be cached in your browser, or server-side (that is, that image hasn't been recalculated yet). You can check your browser by clearing its cache; and refetching it after doing that might get a recalculated version.

Comment: hmm.... I think I know what's going on. The flair is cached server side **per-user**, so what you see is not what others see. I got the correct flair because I never saw it before, so it took a fresh copy. It takes up to 24 hours to update, so if tomorrow at this time it still won't show correct rep, let me know. /cc @Andrew (for what it's worth, all those who didn't see your flair recently will see correct rep)

Comment: @Shadow That seems hugely over-resourcing. Why not create the flair for user 303084 when it's first requested by anyone, and then retain it for re-presentation? Rather than creating the flair whenever anyone requests it and retaining it for that requestor?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I know that updating images are expensive. I think the site goes update the flair every time the page with the flair is loaded. So knowing that this is expensive, SE cache the flair for every user. See also this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280028/why-does-it-take-time-for-the-reputation-in-the-flair-to-get-updated

Comment: I'm not going to say this is a color thing, but it's a color thing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: My black flair is updated. It can that it's was yesterday (02-25) at 4 o'clock PM but on that moment I wasn't online on SE. Working, big business...